# Tomcat7 doesn't initialize my spring configuration

Tags: java, spring

I have a simple maven spring project, when I run the project on the tomcat server, I don't see tomcat load the configuration on the start up.

[image: maven dependencies]
[image: tomcat web application manager]

> ```
> MySpringMvcDispatcherServletInitializer.java
> ```

```
package com.abc.xyz.config;

import 
 org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class MySpringMvcDispatcherServletInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { DemoAppConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

}
```

> DemoAppConfig.java

```
package com.abc.xyz.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

    @Configuration
    @EnableWebMvc
    @ComponentScan("com.abc.xyz")

    public class DemoAppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    }
```

> DemoRestController.java

```
package com.abc.xyz.rest;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class DemoRestController {

    // add code for the "/hello" endpoint

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String sayHello() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }

}
```

> tomcat7 startup log

```
Oct 24, 2018 4:15:45 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:spring-rest-demo' did not find a matching property.
Oct 24, 2018 4:15:45 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:SIT_Dashboard' did not find a matching property.
Oct 24, 2018 4:15:45 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/7.0.82
Oct 24, 2018 4:15:45 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Sep 29 2017 12:23:15 UTC
Oct 24, 2018 4:15:45 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         7.0.82.0
Oct 24, 2018 4:15:45 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 7
Oct 24, 2018 4:15:45 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            6.1
Oct 24, 2018 4:15:45 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
Oct 24, 2018 4:15:45 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\FAST\JDK64\LINKS\JDK8\jre
Oct 24, 2018 4:15:45 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_144-b01
Oct 24, 2018 4:15:45 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Oct 24, 2018 4:15:45 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\FAST\ApacheTomcat\7.0.82\apache-tomcat-7.0.82
Oct 24, 2018 4:15:45 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\FAST\ApacheTomcat\7.0.82\apache-tomcat-7.0.82
Oct 24, 2018 4:15:45 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\FAST\ApacheTomcat\7.0.82\apache-tomcat-7.0.82
Oct 24, 2018 4:15:45 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\FAST\ApacheTomcat\7.0.82\apache-tomcat-7.0.82
Oct 24, 2018 4:15:45 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\FAST\ApacheTomcat\7.0.82\apache-tomcat-7.0.82\wtpwebapps
Oct 24, 2018 4:15:45 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\FAST\ApacheTomcat\7.0.82\apache-tomcat-7.0.82\endorsed
Oct 24, 2018 4:15:45 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
Oct 24, 2018 4:15:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\FAST\JDK64\LINKS\JDK8\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\FAST\JDK64\1.8.0.144\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_64\BIN\;C:\Program Files\Micro Focus\Reflection\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Micro Focus\Reflection\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\1E\SMSNomad\;C:\Program Files\aim\aim-install\bin\;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;C:\FAST\nodejs\6.11.4\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\opt\gate\base91\..\perl\bin;C:\Users\R633368\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\FAST\maven\3.5.0\apache-maven-3.5.0\bin;.
Oct 24, 2018 4:15:45 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Oct 24, 2018 4:15:45 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Oct 24, 2018 4:15:45 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 768 ms
Oct 24, 2018 4:15:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Oct 24, 2018 4:15:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.82
Oct 24, 2018 4:15:46 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase createSecureRandom
WARNING: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [472] milliseconds.
Oct 24, 2018 4:15:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\FAST\ApacheTomcat\7.0.82\apache-tomcat-7.0.82\webapps\docs
Oct 24, 2018 4:15:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory C:\FAST\ApacheTomcat\7.0.82\apache-tomcat-7.0.82\webapps\docs has finished in 101 ms
Oct 24, 2018 4:15:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\FAST\ApacheTomcat\7.0.82\apache-tomcat-7.0.82\webapps\examples
Oct 24, 2018 4:15:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
Oct 24, 2018 4:15:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
Oct 24, 2018 4:15:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: attributeAdded('org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache', 'org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache@6d4352bf')
Oct 24, 2018 4:15:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory C:\FAST\ApacheTomcat\7.0.82\apache-tomcat-7.0.82\webapps\examples has finished in 499 ms
Oct 24, 2018 4:15:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\FAST\ApacheTomcat\7.0.82\apache-tomcat-7.0.82\webapps\host-manager
Oct 24, 2018 4:15:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory C:\FAST\ApacheTomcat\7.0.82\apache-tomcat-7.0.82\webapps\host-manager has finished in 157 ms
Oct 24, 2018 4:15:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\FAST\ApacheTomcat\7.0.82\apache-tomcat-7.0.82\webapps\manager
Oct 24, 2018 4:15:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory C:\FAST\ApacheTomcat\7.0.82\apache-tomcat-7.0.82\webapps\manager has finished in 82 ms
Oct 24, 2018 4:15:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\FAST\ApacheTomcat\7.0.82\apache-tomcat-7.0.82\webapps\ROOT
Oct 24, 2018 4:15:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory C:\FAST\ApacheTomcat\7.0.82\apache-tomcat-7.0.82\webapps\ROOT has finished in 77 ms
Oct 24, 2018 4:15:48 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Oct 24, 2018 4:15:48 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Oct 24, 2018 4:15:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 2191 ms
```

**As you can see, the start up doesn't show it read my spring configuration, please help, thanks in advance**

[tomcat web application manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/arCRH.png)

> Updated: I have a temp fix, (wow,it takes me 2 days to make some progress since there is no ERRORs  at all in the project).
>
> Here is the trick: Right click project => properties=> Deployment
>   Assembly=> add=> choose Java Build Path Entries=>choose Maven
>   Dependencies=> apply=> OK
>
> You can see server log refresh and it finally loads spring
>   configuration, and if you check
>
> tomcat home directory/wtpwebapps/{project name}/WEB-INF/lib, you can
>   see all the maven dependencies are copied to  here
>
> Up to this point, It looks like everything is fine now, but I find the
>   other issue, every time I right click=>maven=> update project...=> it
>   will try to remove the dependencies(jars) in tomcat home
>   directory/wtpwebapps/{project name}/WEB-INF/lib,
>
> If your project is running at the tomcat , you will get a error
>   because these jars are being used.
>
> But if you stop server, and update project and then run as server
>   again, everything is back to normal, no error, no spring configuration
>   in the server startup log,  then you have to do the same trick again.
>
> I tried so many online solutions about "maven project update will
>   remove jars in tomcat server", none of them are working. So if anyone
>   has the the fix, please shared

Comment: Please, show `web.xml` file. How do you deploy your application?

Comment: For this project, I don't use web.xml in the project, it is using pure java configuration and my tomcat version is Apache Tomcat/7.0.82, and all my developing software including maven, eclipse, tomcat are installed from company network, not sure it can cause the problem

Comment: The question about deploying still requires the answer. There are several ways to do that.

Comment: i simply right click the project in project explorer, Run As=>Run on Server, since the default server is tomcat , the tomcat will start if it is not started, then the eclipse browser will point to localhost, "http://localhost:8080/spring-rest-demo/" will show 404 is expected  since I dont have a index.jsp, but I expect "http://localhost:8080/spring-rest-demo/test/hello" will return "hello world" in the browser". but i still get "HTTP Status 404 - /spring-rest-demo/test/hello".

Comment: The application is deployed in server, you can see attached image, just the spring configuration is not loaded, or detected by tomcat,

Comment: I have a update, see post